# подскажите, пожалуйста как удалить кнопку при нажатии на нее

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from aiogram.types import message
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):


    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Хочу пройти тест")

    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Привет, {0.first_name}!\nЯ помогу тебе понять-<b>{1.first_name}</b>-шизик ты или нет. Ответь на следующий вопрос... ".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Хочу пройти тест':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data='bad')


            markup.add(item1, item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'жизнь бессмыслена?', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поторопись, ато тест сейчас закроется')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Обратись к врачу')
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,'Поздравляю, ты здоров')
                
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reply_markup=markup)





            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                                  text="Бро, ты крут!))")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

подскажите, пожалуйста как удалить кнопку при нажатии на нее?